# Call command from exe in bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am currently developing a android app and I am debugging wireless.
Every time I want to do this, I need to open the cmd in a specific direction and type:

```
adb
adb connect 'some ip'
```

adb is a exe and adb connect is some command in adb.exe
I was trying to write a simple bat file for this and I found this on the internet:

```
START C:\Andriod\adb.EXE
```

As you know, this only starts the adb.
I could not find how to call this command, propbably because I do not know the correct name for it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you really launch adb twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  [CALL command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) like this in batch:

```
@echo off

call C:\Andriod\adb.EXE
```

Comment: this runs adb.exe, but how do i call the command 'adb connect "some ip"' in the adb

Comment: can you please add `adb connect 'some ip'` at last line and share the result here as i can't check it at my end.

Comment: it says "abd is not know"

Comment: check this link..(http://zacktutorials.blogspot.in/2013/04/adb-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or.html )

Answer (score -1):

adb -s [yourdeviceserialnumberhere] shell

adb connect {ip:host}

http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-hacks-help/6865-how-use-adb-all-commands-options.html

Comment: I know the commands in the adb, but i do not know how to call them from a batch file.

Comment: set path=%path%;C:\C:\Android then you can use adb without having to include the full path :)

Comment: note that the link in Zacktutorials above is explaining how to set the  Path variable via gui; I was showing you how to do it directly in the *.bat file directly; please remove downvote :(